# Magento Shopping Cart Link Edit

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart

My company is using magento 1.7. The Shopping Cart link at the top has a misspelling. I cannot seem to find the code to correct it. I have tried turning on template path help, but that did not give me a location. I have checked the templates in the theme and the base theme. Where else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a misspelling in a third party extension, I have no idea why the extension even needed to touch the cart as it is completely unrelated. In order to find it, I wrote a program to search through all the files in app and look for the misspelling.